# How to create new instance from class name in gwt

Tags: gwt

I have a class int the following name `com.test.TestClass`

At one point in my code I have to get instance of this class by only having the class name string. I have tried using `GWT.create()` 
But it is working only in dev mode. Can any one tell me how to get instance in gwt from class name.

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451658/gwt-dynamic-loading-using-gwt-create-with-string-literals-instead-of-class-lite

Comment: Thanks.I am also expecting the same .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since reflection is not possible on the client side, the only solution you have to mimic reflection is using deferred binding.

Use deferred binding to discover all classes you wish to instantiate with the class name during compile time. You may use a marker interface on all such classes to aid TypeOracle to identify these. You dynamically generate a factory class, which takes in the simple name of the class and returns a newly instantiated object of that class. The approach is very straight forward and you will find a good explanation of deferred binding in google's tutorials to boot.

**Edit:-**
Some skeletal code to get you started. ***(Stripped down version of my production code, check for compiler errors in the generated file! and debug the flow)***

**First>** Add the following blurb into your *.gwt.xml, to so that the compiler invokes our com.package.ReflectionGenerator, which will generate a simple factory class to mimic reflection on the client side.

```
  <generate-with class="com.package.ReflectionGenerator">
      <when-type-assignable class="com.package.client.Reflection" />
  </generate-with>
```

**Next>** Define an interface for our factory class

```
public interface Reflection {
    public <T, V extends T> T instantiate( Class<V> clazz );
}
```

**Last>** Implement ReflectionGenerator

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gwt.core.ext.BadPropertyValueException;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.Generator;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorContext;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.PropertyOracle;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.TreeLogger;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.TypeOracle;
import com.google.gwt.user.rebind.ClassSourceFileComposerFactory;
import com.google.gwt.user.rebind.SourceWriter;

public class ReflectionGenerator extends Generator
{    
    @Override
    public String generate( TreeLogger logger, GeneratorContext context, String typeName ) throws UnableToCompleteException
    {
        TypeOracle oracle = context.getTypeOracle( );

        JClassType instantiableType = oracle.findType( MarkerInterface.class.getName( ) );

        List<JClassType> clazzes = new ArrayList<JClassType>( );

        PropertyOracle propertyOracle = context.getPropertyOracle( );

        for ( JClassType classType : oracle.getTypes( ) )
        {
            if ( !classType.equals( instantiableType ) && classType.isAssignableTo( instantiableType ) )
                clazzes.add( classType );
        }

        final String genPackageName = "com.package.client";
        final String genClassName = "ReflectionImpl";

        ClassSourceFileComposerFactory composer = new ClassSourceFileComposerFactory( genPackageName, genClassName );
        composer.addImplementedInterface( Reflection.class.getCanonicalName( ) );

        composer.addImport( "com.package.client.*" );

        PrintWriter printWriter = context.tryCreate( logger, genPackageName, genClassName );

        if ( printWriter != null )
        {
            SourceWriter sourceWriter = composer.createSourceWriter( context, printWriter );
            sourceWriter.println( "ReflectionImpl( ) {" );
            sourceWriter.println( "}" );

            printFactoryMethod( clazzes, sourceWriter );

            sourceWriter.commit( logger );
        }
        return composer.getCreatedClassName( );
    }

    private void printFactoryMethod( List<JClassType> clazzes, SourceWriter sourceWriter )
    {
        sourceWriter.println( );

        sourceWriter.println( "public <T, V extends T> T instantiate( Class<V> clazz ) {" );

        for ( JClassType classType : clazzes )
        {
            if ( classType.isAbstract( ) )
                continue;

            sourceWriter.println( );
            sourceWriter.indent( );
            sourceWriter.println( "if (clazz.getName().endsWith(\"." + classType.getName( ) + "\")) {" );
            sourceWriter.indent( );
            sourceWriter.println( "return (T) new " + classType.getQualifiedSourceName( ) + "( );" );
            sourceWriter.outdent( );
            sourceWriter.println( "}" );
            sourceWriter.outdent( );
            sourceWriter.println( );
        }
        sourceWriter.indent();
        sourceWriter.println("return (T) null;");
        sourceWriter.outdent();
        sourceWriter.println();
        sourceWriter.println("}");
        sourceWriter.outdent( );
        sourceWriter.println( );
    }
}
```

This should generate the factory class ReflectionGenerator in your workspace, check the generated file and tweak the source writer code to generate the code you desire.

Usage `GWT.create( Reflection.class ).instantiate( YourClass.class );`

I have used a marker interface `'MarkerInterface'` in the generator to restrict the number of classes supported by the factory, hence as a result all the participating classes must implement `'MarkerInterface'`

Comment: Thanks a lot.If you can post the sample code it will be very useful for me as well as other users.

Comment: I have edited my response to post a skeletal code demonstrating use of  binding. Please go through, and pardon me if you happen to chance upon a compilation error or two, I haven't run the code through the compiler. Am too lazy for that :P

Answer (score 6):

Here is well tested, commented and slightly refactored version of Ashwin Prabhu's code:

https://bitbucket.org/espinosa/z025-gwt-maven-alternative-setup/src/d35a3fb7e627b5598fb763f480e3f76932cf4232/src/main/java/my/code/z025/util/ClassFromStringFactoryGenerator.java?at=master

Example of usage:

```
String targetEntryPointClass = "my.code.client.Sample3";
ClassFromStringFactory classFromStringFactory = GWT.create(ClassFromStringFactory.class);
Object targetEntryPointInstance = classFromStringFactory.instantiate(targetEntryPointClass);
if (targetEntryPointInstance == null) {
      // throw some exception
}
if (targetEntryPointInstance instanceof EntryPoint) {
      ((EntryPoint) targetEntryPointInstance).onModuleLoad();
} else {
      // throw some exception
}
```

See full source code:
https://bitbucket.org/espinosa/z025-gwt-maven-alternative-setup/src/d35a3fb7e627b5598fb763f480e3f76932cf4232/src/main/java/my/code/z025/client/Dispatcher.java?at=master

In my project, I use GWT's own EntryPoint as marker interface. This enables me to run arbitrary EntryPoint just via URL: `http://localhost:8080/my.code.client.Sample3`; the Dispatcher EntryPoint instantiates `my.code.client.Sample3` via my `ClassFromStringFactory`. Only Dispatcher Entry Point is configured in GWT module descriptor and the deferred binding, everything else is dynamic.

For curious, here is what GWT (Code Server in DevMode or Compiler for production mode) generates, content of my ClassFromStringFactoryImpl:

```
package my.code.client.reflection;

public class ClassFromStringFactoryImpl implements ClassFromStringFactory {
  public ClassFromStringFactoryImpl( ) {}

  public Object instantiate(String className) {
    if (className == null) {
      return null
    }
    else if (className.equals("my.code.client.Sample1")) {
      return new my.code.client.Sample1( );
    }
    else if (className.equals("my.code.client.Sample2")) {
      return new my.code.client.Sample2( );
    }
    ..and so on, 3 same lines per every supported type
    return null;
  }
}
```

In temporary file like: `C:\Users\espinosa\AppData\Local\Temp\my.code.client.reflection.ClassFromStringFactoryImpl4245548251877324156.java`.
*Note: this file is generated only in case of failure, not on successful compilation*

As you can see, it is no real introspection. Deferred binding does not do any special magic.
Similar Java code can be generated by a Velocity template as a part of Maven build or special tools like XText, APT-Jelly. Using GWT's Generator is just a convenience.

It is important to limit number of "supported" classes, otherwise the generated `ClassFromStringFactoryImpl` would be too huge, impractically huge or even exceeding limits on Java class. Some sort of filtering is necessary, marking interface is just one option, others are marking annotation (see GWT's JClassType#getAnnotation(Class)) or only selected packages. In any case, ensure that number of supported classes by this "reflection" does not exceeds magnitude of hundreds.

Many thanks Ashwin Prabhu for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

> GWT.create( Reflection.class ).instantiate( YourClass.class );

Why don't you use then just `GWT.create( YourClass.class );` ?

Maybe you ment `GWT.create( Reflection.class ).instantiate( "YourClass" );`

Comment: This should've been posted as a comment under https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035647/ rather than a separate answer.