# What is the generator in Google web toolkit

Tags: gwt

I am new in GWT. I'm confused about the gwt generators. How and when the use of generator in GWT and what is the advantage and limit of GWT generators. Thanks in advance.

Comment: GWT generators are an advanced argument in GWT, if you're at the beginning I suggest you to don't worry about. Otherwise some responses here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298317/what-is-the-use-gwt-generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Fedy2. If you just have started with GWT, don't worry about generaters.

If you are really interessted in generators, take look here:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html#generators

Generaters are used to generate classes or files. Take a look at the RemoteService. You create a service interface and a async interface. GWT uses a generator to create the proxy code and the code for the serialisation and deserialisation.

If you take a look at the GWT Showcase, a generator is used to generate the HTML from the Java Classes to show the coding.

To use a generator, you need a interface (sometimeswith some annotations) and a deferred binding that maps the interface to the generator. To invoke a generator you have to call GWT.create(interface.class).

Generators are normally used, to reduce the amount of code or to simplify things.

Comment: What is the work and use <generator-with> in xml file?