# GWT interface like Constants

Tags: java, gwt, localization

In my application I need to use dynamic localization, so I cannot use Constants interface. I did use Constants for a while, but now I need texts to be changed without compiling so I had to find some other way.

So I am using Dictionary now. The thing is, when I now want to use text in UiBinder, I can only use methods without arguments. So I created class "StringIdentifiers" where I have the same methods I previously had in MyConstants, but I have to specify a body here for every method to return the specified String.

So for example I have:

```
Dictionary locale = Dictionary.getDictionary("myJsObjectWithStrings");

//and then the methods for returning the actual strings from the JS object
String loading(){
   return locale.get("loading");
}
```

I would like the method to only be

```
String loading();
```

since the rest is always the same with the name of the method appearing as String parameter in the get() method. Possibly even returning some default value when the String is missing in the JS object. But I do not know how to do that. I checked the Constants interface, but I do not really understand the code there. Can someone please give me an example how to implement such a thing?

Comment: Why do you mean by dynamic ? Is reloading the page acceptable ?

Comment: Yes, user changes the language on login screen, that reloads the page with different url (http://page.com/index.html?locale=en) corresponding to the language selected. I do it like that, because w/o reloading the page the UiBinder templates will not change. My question is how can I achieve writing only the method signatures (like with Constants) for each string.

Comment: If you reload the page why can't you use the classical GWT mechanism of i18n strings ?

Comment: It is said in the question. It is required that the texts might be changed without compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard feature in GWT to do this, but you could create one yourself. It's a bit of a stretch, but it should work by using the GWT generator mechanisch. In global terms it should work as follows:

1. Create an interface (say `MyMessages`) with a the method names.
2. To use it use `MyMessages message = GWT.create(MyMessages.class)`. Where you need the text  `message.loading()`.
3. Create a generator that generates an class implementing the interface. This class will created at compile time and should contain the implementation of the interface methods, like in your example.
4. Add a [generate-with](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html#generator) tag in your `gwt.xml` file to make it work.

This is a bit of a brief explanation, but I hope it helps. For more background information about generators see: [What is the use GWT generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298317/what-is-the-use-gwt-generator) or http://blog.arcbees.com/2015/05/26/how-to-write-gwt-generators-efficiently/

You could even reuse some of GWT's annotation's of the i18n to add for example default texts. Add the annotation to your interface and in the generator scan the annotation and use it in the code generation part.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is what I was looking for. Hopefully I will be able to implement something like that.