# GWT: application menu and dynamic content creation

Tags: gwt, reflection, panel, dynamic

Scenario: my application makes use of uibinder. I have a splitlayout panel with:

- a menu on the left side of the screen with a few hyperlinks (history support);
- a central SimplePanel bound to the historychanged event like this:

  String historyToken = event.getValue();
  content.setWidget(new Label(historyToken));
- not very useful right? Now I want to populate my  center panel with a dynamically created widget.
- I know that reflection is not possible on the client-side.
- So how can I decide what class to create / add to my content panel, and avoid an awful if / else if / else if / ... block of code, based on the history token?
- I was thinking about using constants in a more elegant "switch" way, but it's substantially the same solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution is using DeferredBinding and write a code generator for a "factory" class.

Answer (score 0):

There is 3rd party support for reflection at client side in GWT. Take a look at [GWT Reflection](http://gwtreflection.sourceforge.net/#overview)

Comment: no thanks, I don't want third party stuff for now... doesn't a whole standard solution exist? what about deferred binding?

Comment: I am afraid deferred binding is not what you are looking for in this case. If you're not familiar with it, please read this it explains ... http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html

Comment: What about that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034881/how-to-create-new-instance-from-class-name-in-gwt

Comment: Haven't tried that yet. If it works for you, than use it :)) Anyway why are you afraid of 3rd party depdendencies? This GWT Reflection I mentioned is small thing :) I suggest you do demo projects and try more to see which works for you best.