# How to create new instance dynamically in GWT?

Tags: class, gwt, gwt-compiler

I have a case, generate an instance  dynamically ie, 
i have map like

```
Map<String,Class> classMap=new HashMap<String,Class>();
classMap.put("key1",Panel.Class);
classMap.put("key2",Panel1.Class);
classMap.put("key3",Panel2.Class);
Class clazz=map.get("key");
GWT.create(clazz);
```

when i compile using  `GWT Compile`  i got the exception

```
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   [ERROR] Errors in 'com/asklepian/web/Sample/sample.java'
      [ERROR] Line 19: Only class literals may be used as arguments to GWT.create()
```

is there is any better way to achieve the same.Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034881/how-to-create-new-instance-from-class-name-in-gwt

Comment: There is no reflection in GWT.  You can only pass things to GWT.create() that are statically compiled into the call.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving class objects is done by adding lowercase ".class" to the classname. 
So maybe change your map to



`classMap.put("key1",Panel.class); 

classMap.put("key2",Panel1.class); 

classMap.put("key3",Panel2.class);` 


and try to recompile with that.