# Instantiate interface in JAVA?

Tags: java, gwt, interface, instantiation

I'm reading the docs on the `UIBinder` of GWT and the first code snippet made me confused:

```
public class HelloWorld extends UIObject { // Could extend Widget instead
  interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<DivElement, HelloWorld> {}
  private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);

  @UiField SpanElement nameSpan;

  public HelloWorld() {
    // createAndBindUi initializes this.nameSpan
    setElement(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
  }
}
```

On the second line an interface is created locally which extends the `UiBinder` interface. However, on the third line an instance of this interface is created using `GWT.create()`.

How is this possible? There's nowhere a class that implements `MyUiBinder`, so it can't be instantiated, right?

Answer (score 3):

`GWT.create` is treated specially by the GWT Java compiler at compile time. The `GWT` class is the place where Google puts the low-level "magic" that makes GWT work.

[More details under this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451658/gwt-dynamic-loading-using-gwt-create-with-string-literals-instead-of-class-lite)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451658/gwt-dynamic-loading-using-gwt-create-with-string-literals-instead-of-class-lite/1395981#1395981) (old in SO terms ;) ) that covers the same topic.

As far as I understand: it does not work magically but with the little help of a generator that knows how to create an instance for a given interface (some MyUIBinderGenerator in your example). And that generator has to be implemented and published in some gwt.xml file.