# How to pass a class as a parameter in java

Tags: java

I would like to pass a class as a parameter in java. [How do I pass a class as a parameter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872978/how-do-i-pass-a-class-as-a-parameter-in-java)

that's the thing I found with answers, but doing it that way doesn't do what I want to.

what I want to do is something like this:

```
public List<cls> getTouchingObjects(Class cls){
    List<cls> thing;
    //fill thing
    return thing;
}
```

it doesn't exactly work though... any idea how I could get this to work?

Comment: You can't do what you want due to Java generics type erasure. Looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) type question regardless. Please consider telling us *why* you want to do this, what overall problem you're trying to solve. You know that generic constants are mainly used for compile-time type safety, and your code is trying to shoehorn this into the run-time world.

Comment: Do you really want a `Class` object, or do you want an instance of an object?  They are two *very* different things.

Comment: It is really difficult to understand what you want to achieve yet the answer from @bowmore seems to be matching best to what you might want

Comment: Yes @Oleg, his solution did work I believe I marked that as such, but if I didn't, it would be nice to know how to do so. Sorry about it not being very specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Class` class takes a generic parameter. So rather than passing `Class cls`, pass `Class<T> cls`.

```
public <T> List<T> getTouchingObjects(Class<T> cls){
    List<T> thing;
    //fill thing
    return thing;
}
```

This allows you to specify the return type, in terms of the class passed as a parameter. The implementation, will still most likely be using introspection.

Of course as it is this can still allow clients to pass a class that is nonsensical to your context. I guess whatever your method does, it won't be applicable to Strings, yet nothing prevents calling `getTouchingObjects(String.class)`. You haven't specified what type those touching objects have generally, but for the sake of example I'll assume they ought to be subclasses of `ChessPiece`. In that case you'd narrow the method down like this :

```
public <T extends ChessPiece> List<T> getTouchingObjects(Class<T> cls){
    List<T> thing;
    //fill thing
    return thing;
}
```

Like that, calling `getTouchingObjects(String.class)` won't even compile, and you've improved your type safety even more.

Comment: Why even have a `cls` parameter for this code or any method parameter at all? It's not needed, not used, and the only purpose it serves is to confuse.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels not really useless. Client code can avoid casting by passing the class it expects. It's the implemntation's job to make sure it's type safe.